# Error in 4.5 Expression must be a group key or aggregate

Tags: database, couchbase, sql++

After upgrading to Couchbase 4.5 I have started getting this error "Expression must be a group key or aggregate (`write`.`timestamp`)","code":4210}. I'm i doing something wrong here? here is my query

`select max(timestamp) as lastDetect, count(timestamp) as detectCount 
from write 
where docType is not missing AND docType = 'DetectRecord' AND proximityUUID = $uuid AND major = $major AND minor = $minor AND timestamp BETWEEN $startTime AND $endTime ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 1;`

Example document:

`{
       "id": "1234k",
       "docType": "DetectRecord",
       "proximityUUID": "12kdf",
       "major": "dkf",
       "minor": "ad",
       "timestamp": 1464954200000
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was caused by a change added to couchbase 4.5 (http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/release-notes/relnotes.html). Changing the query to the following resolved this for me.

```
select max(timestamp) as lastDetect, count(timestamp) as detectCount 
from write 
where docType is not missing AND docType = 'DetectRecord' AND proximityUUID = $uuid AND major = $major AND minor = $minor AND timestamp BETWEEN $startTime AND $endTime 
GROUP BY timestamp
ORDER BY timestamp desc limit 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes Marquis, N1QL enforces the correct GROUP BY syntax/semantics in 4.5. This is mentioned in release notes "behavior changes": http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/release-notes/relnotes.html